# Why does the addition of precise numbers give an imprecise result in R?

Tags: r, precision

I would like to add precise numbers together, and get a precise result. I know that I need to set my desired digit length in the options. For example:

```
> options(digits=20)
> x <- 42.616999999999997 + 42.405999999999999 + 42.869
```

I expect to get an answer with the level of precision set. In the above case:

```
> x
[1] 127.89199999999999591
```

This result is duly produced on my personal computer, but I cannot replicate it on my work computer, which - with the exact same code and the exact same environment (no difference in packages) - produces the following result:

```
> x
[1] 127.892
```

I am unclear about what else could differ between my personal and work computer. It might be useful to know that my personal computer is running R version 3.6.2, while my work computer is running 3.4.2 (I cannot update it because of installation restrictions).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: 32 bit vs 64 bit, probably

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `help("options")` we read:

> digits: controls the number of significant (see signif) digits to
>   print when printing numeric values. It is a suggestion only. Valid
>   values are 1...22 with default 7. See the note in print.default about
>   values greater than 15.

Your value is greater than 15, so let's check the note in `help("print.default")`:

> Large number of digits
>
> Note that for large values of digits, currently
>   for digits >= 16, the calculation of the number of significant digits
>   will depend on the platform's internal (C library) implementation of
>   sprintf() functionality.

This explains why you observe different results on different computers. Indeed, on my system:

```
options(digits=20)
42.616999999999997 + 42.405999999999999 + 42.869
#[1] 127.892
```

However, you can enforce a specific number of digits after the decimal point by using the R function `sprintf`:

```
sprintf("%.17f", 42.616999999999997 + 42.405999999999999 + 42.869)
#[1] "127.89199999999999591"
```

Note that all of this is only about how numbers are printed. Internally, R uses always double precision (please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059) to understand the consequences).

If you need more precise results you'd need to use arbitrary precision numbers, e.g., by using the R package [Rmpfr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rmpfr/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, this is a really great answer!